# Memory management tips on initialising variables?

Tags: android, performance, android-memory

I'm trying to reduce the risk of my app running into `Memory Leaks`, and i'm currently focusing on tiding up my initialisation of variables as a quick fix.
For example,

```
public void renameItems(Activity activity, ...) {

AlertDialog.Builder builderInner = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(activity);
    final TextView itemTitle = new TextView(activity);
    final EditText itemTitleInput = new EditText(activity);
    final TextView subItem = new TextView(activity);
    final EditText subItemInput = new EditText(activity);

// Irrelevant code ...

}
```

Whenever this method is called, are new instances of these variables being created each time? If so, how would i nullify them when im done?

I've also tried changing the scope of the variables, but i need to pass a context to them (which i receive from the method), and i'm unsure how i would do that on a global scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this isn't the exact answer to solution for the code to provided, but you asked for a general solution to handle/detect memory leask inside your application, right?

The Godmaster Jake Wharton released a nice tool to detect potential memory leaks some time ago:
It's called LeakCanary

It's really easy to integrate in your app! **(BUT BE CAREFUL NOT ADDING IT TO THE RELEASE BUILD!!!)**

On the [github page](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) it is described how to integrate LeakCanary to your app:

In your build.gradle:

```
 dependencies {
   debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4'
   releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4'
   testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4'
 }
```

In your Application class:

```
public class ExampleApplication extends Application {

  @Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    LeakCanary.install(this);
  }
}
```

Sooooo... But now you have a leak and what next?
From my personal experience be aware doing something like this:

- try to avoid saving an Activity or an Activity context as a class
  member. Use always the application context instead, if it's possible!
- try to avoid creating layout via runtime! Inflate them by using a xml-layout
- if you are using EventBus, RxJava/RxAndroid, and so on: don't forget to unsubscribe from the tools/framworks/providers you are
  using. If they are not unsubscribed after the Activity runs into
  `onPause()` or `onStop()`
- If you are really afraid of creating variables inside your method, try to avoid to create all variables at the top of a method, create them when you need them! In Java you don't have nullify/terminate them! That's why you have the Garbage Collection!